# How to add Variable to JSON Python Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

```
 class GetRouteDriver(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, username, origin, destination):  
        origin_lat, origin_lng = origin.split(',')
        destination_lat, destination_lng = destination.split(',')
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&key'+ GOOGLE_KEY 
        request_data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        serialized_data = request_data.read()
        id = '1'
        ride = json.loads(serialized_data)

        return Response( ride, status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

i want to add  the ID to the ride retrived from Google Maps API

and with the code from above i Got this and this is what i want.
[image]

if i Concatenate The  ID i get this
[image]

this is the code with the concatenation

```
class GetRouteDriver(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, username, origin, destination):  
        origin_lat, origin_lng = origin.split(',')
        destination_lat, destination_lng = destination.split(',')
        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&key'+ GOOGLE_KEY 
        request_data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        #serialized_data = request_data.read()
        serialized_data = json.dumps({'ride_id': 1, 'route': request_data.read()})
        ride = json.loads(serialized_data)
        return Response( ride, status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's not working? Are you getting errors? Help us help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i just made this i load the json from the google Response before  make jason.dumps like in this code .

```
class GetRouteDriver(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)    
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    def get(self, request, username, origin, destination):  
        origin_lat, origin_lng = origin.split(',')
        destination_lat, destination_lng = destination.split(',')

        url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=' + origin + '&destination=' + destination + '&key'+ GOOGLE_KEY 
        request_data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        #serialized_data = request_data.read()

        serialized_data = json.dumps( { 'ride_id': 1 , 'route': json.loads(request_data.read()) })
        route = json.loads(serialized_data)
        return Response( route, status=status.HTTP_200_OK )
```

And now i get what i want .

[image]